# Visual Studio solutions in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, qt4, qt-creator

I am using Qt 4.5 and having Qt Creator as the IDE. I am quite comfortable with it. I know we can open the `.pro` files (from the Qt Creator) in the Visual Studio IDE. But how about the reverse? i.e **How can I open a visual studio Qt solution (.sln) in Qt Creator**? Is it possible or I have to create a pro file again for the project?

There are other Qt projects which are created by others in Visual Studio IDE. So if I am supposed to use those, **can I migrate those Visual Studio solutions to a Qt Creator compatible way** so that I can continue to use Qt Creator? I am using Windows XP. Any pointers regarding this are welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can install Visual Studio Add-in of Qt, then in Visual Studio, Qt menu will appear.There is an export option to create .pro files.

Edit: [Detailed Information](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/vs-integration-1.4/vs-integration-managing-projects.html#importing-and-exporting-projects)

Comment: I searched for the Export option you mentioned. But I couldn't find an export option to convert Visual Studio Solution (sln) to pro files.. Could you be more specific about where I can find the export option? I have the Visual Studio Add-in added already..

Comment: Can you see Qt on the Menu? There is a "Create basic .pro file" option. Also look at here http://doc.qt.nokia.com/vs-integration-1.4/vs-integration-managing-projects.html#importing-and-exporting-projects